# Django, mod_python, apache deployment: mod_python import error

Tags: django, apache, mod-python

I've already installed mod_python, but when i'm trying to use it:

eg.

```
>>>import mod_python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named mod_python
```

-

```
[root@lab6 /]# yum install mod_python
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Setting up Install Process
Package mod_python-3.2.8-3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I can't import it even though i've already 
installed it in a Redhat server.

And it's suposed to be used to deploy Django in a Redhat server with this httpd.conf entry:

```
<VirtualHost mritest2.domain.ch:80>
        ServerName mritest2.domain.ch
        DocumentRoot /home/django_www/hardi

        <Location "/">
            SetHandler python-program
            PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
            SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mri.settings
            PythonDebug On

            PythonPath "['/home/django_www', '/home/django_www/hardi'] + sys.path"
        </Location>

        <Location "/static/">
            SetHandler None
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_python is a HTTPd module, not a Python package; its virtual modules are only available to code it is running, not the REPL.

But in truth mod_python has been [dead for a while now](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html), and you should migrate to mod_wsgi ASAP.

Comment: thanks, I've another question regarding mod_wsgi:

I'was trying to install it - 
"sudo ./configure --with-python=/opt/python2.5/bin/python"

But i couldn't find this dir: "/opt/python2.5/bin/python" in my filesystem.. Is there any other way to install mod_wsgi?

Comment: just tried it, but it doesn't work: "No package mod_wsgi available.
"

Comment: problem solved: i found the dir at: "/root/epd-5.1.0/bin/python", thanks!